# Pair of Jacks at the final table

Tags: poker-strategy

Shall I shove with a medium stack close to a big money? I have a pair of Jacks at the UTG.

Any thoughts in regard of that?

Comment: The answer may depends if you're either in a SNG and there are some short stacks or MTT. Though, _big money_ doesn't sound like a SNG but that's relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most things poker, it depends. I presume your goal here is to maximize your profit in this tournament, and you want to know what action with your JJ is most likely to maximize your profit in the whole tournament.  Some things your decision depends on:

1. How many players remain?
2. How many blinds do you have overall?
3. What are the prizes for each remaining place?
4. What are the exact stack levels of other players?

In general, what you are asking is the question that the [ICM](http://www.thepokerbank.com/strategy/tournament/icm/what/) (independent chip model) is intended to address. It's a way to help decide questions of equity near the end of a tournament which will help you translate an action into a dollar amount.

Answer (score -3):

Mid raise, call any reraise, play the flop, bet it if like Q95...go from there...

Comment: This response is 100% devoid of any nuance. What if the reraiser is the massive chip leader at the table and he will put you all in?  And you just have jacks.

Comment: If you could expand on your answer, maybe include your reasoning, thought process and logic that would be better. As Chris said what if the re-raiser is chip leader, different situations require different approaches and logic.